# Как перекомпилировать С# библиотеку под другую версию .NET?

Tags: c#, .net, dll, nuget

Мне нужно скачать библиотеку с NuGet, но я получаю ошибку

> Не удалось установить пакет «SharpFont.Dependencies 2.5.5». Вы пытаетесь установить этот пакет в проект, требуемая версия платформы которого — «.NETFramework,Version=v4.7.2», но в пакете нет ссылок на сборки или файлов содержимого, совместимых с этой платформой.

Есть [ссылка](https://github.com/Robmaister/SharpFont) на её github. Я скачал библиотеку, поменял версию на 4.7.2. Нажимаю *пересобрать решение*, но получаю ошибки:

> Ошибка    CS0006  Не удалось найти файл метаданных "C:\Users\UserName\Desktop\SharpFont-master\Source\SharpFont.GDI\bin\Debug\SharpFont.Gdi.dll".
>
> Ошибка    CS0227  Небезопасный код может использоваться только при компиляции с параметром /unsafe.   SharpFont.Gdi   C:\Users\UserName\Desktop\SharpFont-master\Source\SharpFont.GDI\FTBitmapExtensions.cs

Answer (score 1):

> Ошибка CS0006 Не удалось найти файл метаданных
>   C:\Users\UserName\Desktop\SharpFont-master\Source\SharpFont.GDI\bin\Debug\SharpFont.Gdi.dll
>
> Ошибка CS0227 Небезопасный код может использоваться только при
>   компиляции с параметром /unsafe. SharpFont.Gdi
>   C:\Users\UserName\Desktop\SharpFont-master\Source\SharpFont.GDI\FTBitmapExtensions.cs

В `SharpFont.Gdi.csproj` не определена опция [AllowUnsafeBlocks](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/compiler-options/unsafe-compiler-option) для `Debug` конфигурации, которая разрешает компиляцию `Unsafe` кода. Для `Release` определение есть:

```
<PropertyGroup Condition=" '$(Configuration)|$(Platform)' == 'Release|AnyCPU' ">
  <DebugType>pdbonly</DebugType>
  <Optimize>true</Optimize>
  <OutputPath>bin\Release\</OutputPath>
  <DefineConstants>TRACE</DefineConstants>
  <ErrorReport>prompt</ErrorReport>
  <WarningLevel>4</WarningLevel>
  <AllowUnsafeBlocks>true</AllowUnsafeBlocks>
  <Prefer32Bit>false</Prefer32Bit>
</PropertyGroup>
```

Включите опцию для других конфигураций.

---

Можно *попробовать* привести `.csproj` файлы к `.NET.Sdk` виду и свести кол-во определений к минимуму и одной строкой определить под какие версии фреймворка собирать проект:

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFrameworks>net45;net462;net472</TargetFrameworks>
  </PropertyGroup>

</Project>
```